# Creating a configurable Magento attribute from scratch

Tags: magento

I need to extend Magento to allow changing the price of a product based on an attribute, such as size or color. I can't use any in-built facilities Magento might have for this - I need to write the code myself. I'm a beginning Magento developer. Can anybody help? Maybe point me to a guide or walk-through for this on the internet? Thanks!

Comment: If you could post why you think the configurable products will not work for you, we may be able to help you. You may be able to get the pricing worked out without any additional programming.

Comment: I'm a beginning PHP developer just starting out with Magento, and my boss wants me to write the code from scratch for educational purposes. I'm sure the default functionality will work just fine without additional programming, but that's not an option for me. I need to produce (and explain) some code! :s

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read some of the basic guides on Magento to answer a question like this. This is entirely the point of configurable products and of custom product options.

Hope that helps

Thanks,
Joe